# Unity container DI, does container.Resolve<> need to be called eveywhere in the code base

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, console-application, unity-container

I've a console application. I've registered all the types (12K classes) in my application into the container. For DI to happen, do I need to do container.Resolve<> everywhere in my code base instead of using new() or do I do container.Resolve<> only at the entrypoint class.

I've tried just the entrypoint class and the DI did not happen in a class
2 levels down from the entrypoint class (specifically [Dependency] property injection) does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

you can use of Startup class and config IOC Container in that class.you can use Marker Interface (please search about Marker Interface pattern in google) to resolve all class that there are in your project to implement Dependency Injection to your classes.if you need a specific interface when there is in a specific class constructor you must use DI and register all interface in your application before the app run your code.
I think this code can help you:
this code with Autofac:

`builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();`

`Assembly serviceLayerAssembly = typeof(IUserServices).Assembly;`

```
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies: serviceLayerAssembly)
            .AssignableTo<IMarkedServiceInterface>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies: serviceLayerAssembly)
            .AssignableTo<IMarkedMapperInterface>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Comment: I'm registering all the types returned by AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() i@ startup in my Unity container. Do I need to change all the code that says new Foo() now to say container.Resolve<Foo>()?

Comment: you need register all class that there are in your project. you can register your class with using Refrection or you must manually register your class if you want to use Dependency Injection in your project.but you do not need to change your classes.